# Pandas switching value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to switch the group number by the people of number, the table like this below

```
|   uid  |  group |
| ------ | ------ |
| 355    | 1      |
| 356    | 3      |
| 357    | 4      |
| 358    | 3      |
| 359    | 5      |
| 360    | 6      |...
```

want to switch the number if the people in group 1 rename to group 5, if in group 3 rename to group 6...
how can I able to change the value? I try to

```
df['group'] = df['group'][df['group'] == 1] + 4 
df['group'] = df['group'][df['group'] == 3] + 3
```

but i also calculate the NAN value to the dataframe
i also try to

```
df['group'][df['group'] == 5] = df['group'][df['group'] == 10]
```

by add all group by 10 from the start, but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mapping dictionary:

```
d = {1: 5, 3: 6}

df['group'] = df['group'].map(lambda x: d.get(x, x))
```

Or if you want to use an addition:

```
d = {1: 4, 3: 3}

df['group'] = df['group'].add(df['group'].map(d), fill_value=0)
```

output (as new column "group2" for clarity):

```
   uid  group  group2
0  355      1       5
1  356      3       6
2  357      4       4
3  358      3       6
4  359      5       5
5  360      6       6
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use loc for this and assign the group with it

```
df.loc[ {your condition}, {the column that you want to update}] = {new value}
```

by replacing those {}, for your first example this is the code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'uid': [355,356,357,358,359,360],
    'group': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]
})

df.loc[df["group"]==1,"group"]=5
df.loc[df["group"]==3,"group"]=6
```

the output is this

```
    uid group
0   355 5
1   356 2
2   357 6
3   358 4
4   359 5
5   360 6
```